# execvp error on file ./Fan (No such file or directory)

Tags: c++, mpi, condor

Here is my MPI_Bcast code first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int rank;
    int data=0;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    //means processors from 0 to 10
    if (rank == 0){
        data = 10;
    }
     printf("/nbefore bcast data in Process %d : %d" , rank, data);

     MPI_Bcast(&data,1,MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("/nafter bcast data in Process %d : %d" , rank, data);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

After run, the "outcome" said: [proxy:0:0@condo038] HYDU_create_process (../../utils/launch/launch.c:825): execvp error on file ./Fan (No such file or directory).

[screenshot of the "outcome"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJW0z.png)

Does anyone know what happened?

1. Is the code correct?
2. How to get expected outcome?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure the binary is available on all the nodes?